# Android APK and Debug install multiple versions of the app

Tags: java, android, gradle, apk

When I'm debugging or even in a final APK release, app installs 5 different versions of the app. They appear in the app drawer as 5 copies of the the same app but when I open one of them, it a old version. One of the installed apps are current. When I uninstall one of these copies all of them uninstall at once.

Comment: Show your manifest file...

Answer (score 2):

You need to take care of Android Manifest file. You need to put following code to only startup activity not on every activity.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```